# Java: What's the right way of writing a generic HashMap merge method?

Tags: java, generics, merge, hashmap

This is probably a basic Java question but I somehow can't find the right keywords to google for the right solution.

I have several pairs of `HashMap` objects and I need to merge each respective pair in a straightforward ways: if two keys match, add up the two values and store the sum in the first map. So I might have something like:

```
HashMap<String,Double> mapSD1, mapSD2;
HashMap<String,Integer> mapSI1, mapSI2;
HashMap<MyClassA,Float> mapCF1, mapCF2;
```

What is the right way of writing a generic `mergeMaps` methods that can merge all these types, instead of having 3 more or less identical methods for each type?

Comment: As a best practice, you should be using `Map<>` instead of `HashMap<>` to hold references to your `HashMap<>` instances.  That is true generally -- use specific implementation types when creating collections, and use interface types to hold their references.  It reduces your code's maintainability if you are unnecessarily specific in the types you use--if you should choose a different implementation of `Map<>` you would be forced to refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no generic way to add numbers of different types. You would have to tell the method how to add to `Float` values, two `Integer` values etc.

Since you are using Java 7, you will have to prepare some ground first. You could create the following interface:

```
public interface BinaryOperator<T> {

    T apply(T t1, T t2);
}
```

Then you could do:

```
private static final BinaryOperator<Float> ADD_FLOATS = new BinaryOperator<Float>() {
    @Override
    public Float apply(Float t1, Float t2) {
        return t1 + t2;
    }
};

public static <K, V> void merge(Map<K, V> map1, Map<K, V> map2, BinaryOperator<V> op) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> e : map2.entrySet()) {
        V val = map1.get(e.getKey());
        if (val == null) {
            map1.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        } else {
            map1.put(e.getKey(), op.apply(val, e.getValue()));
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Float> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", 1.2F);
    map.put("B", 3.4F);
    Map<String, Float> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("B", 5.6F);
    map2.put("C", 7.8F);
    merge(map, map2, ADD_FLOATS);
    System.out.println(map);   // prints {A=1.2, B=9.0, C=7.8}
}
```

When you upgrade to Java 8 you will be able to get rid of `BinaryOperator` (it's already there), and there would be no need to create `ADD_FLOATS`. You will be able to just do

```
merge(map, map2, Float::sum);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still using Java 7. But thank you anyway

Comment: @IZ I've completely rewritten my answer. This may be more what you're looking for?